# Should I have all models done before I syncdb?

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure if I want to add more attributes to my models or create another model. I've coded up to the point where I need to `syncdb` to start using some data in the site, but I'm hesitant to do it. As long as I'm still in production for a while, I could clear the database and start fresh I suppose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`syncdb` is deprecated since version 1.7. [`migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate) is used as it performs both the old behavior as well as executing migrations. So if you are using version smaller than 1.7, you would need to create new table in case any changes in table schema. Or you can use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).

Refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1605662/django-syncdb-and-an-updated-model

I would suggest to shift to latest version of Django to take advantage of build-in migration support.

Comment: I'm using Django 1.7